# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Meta y Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, meta, stackexchange

Encontré este sitio (Meta) hace unos minutos y veo que hay preguntas que no serían aceptadas [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

**¿Cuál es el objetivo de este sitio? ¿En qué es diferente al otro? ¿Cuáles preguntas se formulan aquí?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Stack Overflow en español Meta es la parte del sitio donde los usuarios discuten sobre el funcionamiento y las políticas de Stack Overflow en español en lugar de discutir sobre Stack Overflow en español. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas separado del sito principal que provee un espacio legítimo a las personas para preguntas sobre cómo y por qué el sitio funciona como lo hace.

Recomiendo leer el artículo completo.

Básicamente, [*meta*](https://dle.rae.es/meta-?m=form) se refiere a lo que define la RAE: *acerca de*. Este es un sitio que habla *acerca* del sitio principal para ver cómo gestionarlo y mejorarlo.