# Sería Correcto: Editar un post cuando

Tags: discusión

Partiendo de lo que dice el Centro de ayuda, cuando un usuario gana el privilegio de edición:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

> ¿Qué es la edición de preguntas y respuestas? Creemos en el poder de
> que la comunidad edite. Esto quiere decir que cuando has conseguido
> suficiente reputación, confiamos en ti para editar cualquier cosa en
> el sistema sin que ello deba ser revisado por otras personas. No
> solamente tus publicaciones, sino ¡las de todo el mundo!
>
> ¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones? Siempre que veas que puedes
> mejorar una publicación y te apetezca. ¡Fomentamos la edición!
>
> Algunas razones comunes para editar son:
>
> - para corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía
> - para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla
> - para corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece
> - para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados

## Antecedentes:

Ahora veamos este post de META: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2272/315134
*(11 votos positivos, 2017)*

En donde se ha votado positivamente a que se cumpla con lo que dice el Centro de Ayuda.

***Y cito la sección que más me ha gustado:***

> La pregunta que enlazas sin duda necesita ser mejorada para ser
> aceptable. Siéntete libre de editarla para alcanzar los estándares del
> sitio. Pero ten en cuenta que si el autor original se mostrase en
> desacuerdo con tu edición debes respetar su criterio en general.

Otra publicación de Meta Mas reciente dice lo siguiente:

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4867/315134 *(6 votos positivos, 2020)*

Este punto de la respuesta cita especificamente si es aceptable mover codigo de un comentario a hacia el contenido del post.

> Es admisible
>
> que un usuario se tome la molestia de copiar desde un comentario hacia
> la pregunta. No es una acción reprobable, puesto que la edición
> colabora a mejorar la pregunta en sí. No considero que sea necesario
> revertir ni rechazar esa edición.

***En que momento esto Cambio y en donde esta ese cambio escrito?***

## Escenario actual:

*Se ha suscitado el siguiente escenario. Un usuario a creado el siguiente post:*

https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/612761/1

El cual inicialmente carecía de información que demostrara el esfuerzo y/o un ejemplo mínimo reproducible de lo que tenía (por lo tanto puede ser cerrada y no es el objetivo de este post discutir temas de cierre).

***El usuario en un comentario indica lo siguiente (El Recurso que hacía falta):***

> `<td data-titulo="HORA"><input class='form-control' type='time' min="08:00" max="11:00" id='horaInput'/></td>` este es mi campo se
> podria hacer con js

## Nuevo Planteamiento:

La Moderación del Sitio indica que no es correcto editar el post, tomar el Recurso que está en el comentario y Agregarlo al contenido de la publicación.

En este escenario especifico la Moderación ***Exige*** que sea el OP quien Edite y agregue los datos, Anulando en el proceso todas las ediciones realizadas.

## Personalmente

Creo que la moderación puede tener parte de la razón buscando que el OP aprenda a editar su propio contenido, pero estoy casi seguro de que no es esa la interpretación que indica el centro de ayuda y lo que en general historicamente ha aceptado la comunidad.

***Aclaro que en este escenario el Código no es inventado para decir que la publicación está siendo vandalizada.***

***Aclaro también que en otros caso esta práctica se ha hecho y no es hasta ahora que hay una represalia por parte de la Moderación***

Creo que el Usuario en cuestión que ha editado la pregunta...***ha mantenido la intención y el significado original.*** y segun lo que se ha expuesto, ***es el OP*** quien deberia reversar las ediciones si no esta de acuerdo.

***Entonces caemos en la siguiente premisa:***

> ¿Es válido copiar cualquier información adicional que agregue el
> usuario como comentario y que debería ser una edición, estar en el
> contenido de la publicación?

Comment: Todos somos **la moderación**. ¿O te refieres a un moderador electo? Yo voté esa pregunta a cierre, porque estaba moderando el sitio. Al OP se le dió una respuesta sin pedirle que agregara código a su pregunta. El OP agregó el código en un comentario en la respuesta, porque la respuesta usa código propio y no uno proporcionado por OP. Pero lo importante es: ¿costaba mucho ayudar al OP a editar la pregunta primero y responder luego? Esto ya se ha discutido en el pasado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por la pregunta, me refiero a la descicion de reversion y la justificacion de quien ejecuto la reversion... el cierre me da igual y no es lo que se esta discutiendo en este post ... como objetivo central

Comment: La edición de la pregunta para agregar código la hizo quien respondió. Luego, un usuario (no diamantado) realizó una primera reversión, y el mismo usuario que había editado, vuelve a revertir la pregunta para que figure el código añadido. Este usuario no diamantado entró al chat y pidió opinión de quienes estaban allí. Es en ese momento cuando otro usuario diamantado revisa la edición y la vuelve a revertir. Y si se volviera a editar agregando código que sólo existe en un comentario en la respuesta, y yo viera esa edición, ten por seguro que la volvería a revertir.

Comment: No recuerdo haber trasladado contenido de un comentario a la pregunta, pero **si** del título a la pregunta. *...buscando que el OP aprenda a editar su propio contenido...* es mucho pedir a los usuarios nuevos que se quedan con reputación de "1". Las veces que lo he hecho ha sido [por el sitio], puesto que hay preguntas que pudieran tener algo de potencial, pero nunca van a serán bien indexadas con esos títulos poco precisos.

Comment: no, ese no fue el orden en que pasaron las cosas ... el comentario del codigo llego hace 20 horas en un comentario que estava en la respuesta de Yussef y Yussef el usuario que le daba seguimiento, edito la pregunta despues, segun registro del sistema, el hecho que Yussef se haya adelantado a responder no cambia nada... simplemente era quien estaba dandole seguimiento a todo en ese post.

Comment: @aeportugal y no te has topado un link externo .... y te ha tocado pasar el contenido de ese link externo a dentro del contenido, yo si lo he visto ... principalmente por el tema de la preservacion del codigo/recurso...

Comment: Ahora, en cuanto a tu pregunta: ¿Sería correcto...? En mi opinión, y suponiendo que así sucedan los hechos: si se le pide al OP que añada el código relevante y éste lo hace en un comentario en su propia pregunta, siendo que es un usuario nuevo, basta con indicarle que edite la pregunta y añada ese código a la pregunta. Pero nunca editar una pregunta para copiar el código del comentario a la pregunta por mi cuenta. Suena egoista o tal vez indolente con el OP, pero la idea es propiciar el buen uso y entendimiento del sitio y no dar la impresión que aquí hacemos "favores".

Comment: @MauricioContreras Tienes razon, pero si otro usuario hace caso omiso de tu opinion particular ... **segun los post del 2017 y 2020, no tiene sentido reversarlo, si se respeta el objetivo del post**  ... que es el objetivo de esta discucion/post de meta. que fue en lo que intervino la moderacion e impuso su criterio/ o Interpretación personal de los post que cito.

Comment: @MauricioContreras La idea es crear una base de conocimiento y como mucho educar en lo que se refiere a programación y desarrollo. Educar en lo relativo al buen uso del sitio es secundario, hay quienes le gusta hacerlo y bien por ellos, en este caso nadie le dijo

Comment: Las citas de tu pregunta, relacionadas con los posts de 2017 y 2020, pues IMHO, siendo que la más reciente es de 2020, con esa me quedo. Tu citas una minúscula parte de todo lo que allí se expone en las diferentes respuestas. Por lo que has aplicado un sesgo a tu pregunta, tomando partido en una posición.

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo que pasa es que en esa publicacion trauma hace un listado y no segrega su opinion de lo que el concideraria aceptable ... yo he dado una respuesta en donde si he organizado el contenido...

Comment: podras ver que no he cambiado en nada el contexto del post de trauma, simplemente he organizado los puntos ... para que quede más claro.

Comment: En la del 2020 está la respuesta de Patricio con mismo puntaje

Comment: Estimado Francisco pasa que ni los Mod se ponen de acuerdo consigo mismo. A mi está situación me parece de lo más extraña, yo muchas veces había agregado el código del OP en la pregunta sin problemas. Aquí un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567693/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-c%c3%b3digo-de-%c3%a1rea-de-un-pa%c3%ads-desde-su-n%c3%bamero esta respuesta fue reabierta por ¿G3rv4? al yo haber colocado el código que puso el OP en un link, esto fue validado y agradecido por gbianchi https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWYfX.png pero hoy resulta que por colocar un simple `<input>` armaron un lio enorme

Comment: es que ellos no tienen que estar de acuerdo... entre ellos deben haber diferencias por que son humanos... a mi me parece extraño que esten todos de acuerdo con algo... ya que si ese algo es incorrecto... entonces estariamos en el camino errado siempre ...

Comment: yo espero que la comunidad se ponga de acuerdo y vote... ya gbianchi dijo que el puede estar equivocado no es dueño de la verdad absoluta ... pero si no votan es como que no les interesara el asunto ...

Answer (score 3):

Hare lo mismo que trauma en 2020 ya que concidero que comparto igual opinion que el, aunque quisiera ser más claro... En donde su respuesta da una interpretación personal mejorando o aclarando puntos grises con respecto a [la publicación de 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2261/es-correcto-editar-una-pregunta-cerrada-de-otro-usuario-para-mejorarla/2272#2272)... En este escenario tratare de ser un poco más claro y preciso, aportando organización a los puntos:

---

#### Mi opinión:

***- No se debería hacer,***

Por la sencilla razón de que ***es responsabilidad del autor formular una pregunta correctamente***, lo cual incluye todas las ediciones necesarias después de la publicación inicial.

***- No es recomendable,***

Puesto que se *malacostumbra* al autor. Es su responsabilidad, no de la comunidad.

***- Es inadmisible,***

En publicaciones de usuarios con cierta veteranía. ***Personalmente*** tengo mi nota de corte en los 150 puntos. A partir de ahí, considero que el usuario ya está habituado a las normas del sitio. Si el usuario entra en esta categoría, voto negativo sin piedad y, opcionalmente, dejo un comentario.

---

### Excepciones que yo haría (tambien estan citadas por trauma):

***- Es un requisito,***

Dejar un comentario al autor, del tipo

> Hola. He añadido el código a tu pregunta, porque todos los detalles
> deberían estar en la propia pregunta. Te he hecho un favor
> considerando que eres un usuario nuevo. Por favor, consulta [¿Cómo
> elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿cómo hacer un Ejemplo mínimo
> reproducible?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Un saludo.

***- Es admisible,***

Que un usuario se tome la molestia de copiar desde un comentario hacia la pregunta. No es una acción reprobable, puesto que la edición colabora a mejorar la pregunta en sí. ***No considero que sea necesario revertir ni rechazar esa edición.***

***- Solo para usuarios nuevos,***

Que no suelen conocer como funcionamos y tienden a considerar SOes como un foro cualquiera.

---

#### Consideración personal:

El sitio y la comunidad tiene otra prioridades de mayor importancia, reversar ediciones en donde se traslada información, no tienen sentido. siempre y cuando se respete las normas del sitio indicadas en el centro de ayuda, el criterio general del OP, quien deberia descidir si la reversa ...

***Auto-Respuesta a la Premisa:*** siguiendo los criterios expuesto en las publicacion de 2017 y 2020 (opiniones personales que fueron votadas positivamente) y en general aceptadas positivamente por la comunidad, concedero que la prioridad es Mejorar el Contenido del Sitio por sobre lo que el usuario aprenda... haciendo referencia a que estos usuarios normalmente nuevo... no regresan y no les interesa el sitio... se debe agragar sea por parte del OP o de la comunidad, cualquier contenido que mejores las publicaciones sustancialmente o de un mejor contexto...

> *"Quien soy yo para reversar el trabajo voluntario de otro usuario que busca mejorar el contenido del sitio."*

Answer (score 3):

Aloha~ vamos viendo cómo resolver el asunto, esta situación es interesante y estresante al mismo tiempo.

Voy a clasificar las preguntas del siguiente modo:

**Preguntas que tienen enlaces con código fuente**

*Considerando fuera del mapa al OP: ¿Debería un usuario común y silvestre, y/o moderador editar la pregunta extrayendo el código del enlace para ponerlo en la pregunta?*

No.

**Preguntas que no tienen enlaces con código fuente y que tampoco tienen código.**

Considerando:

1. Fuera del mapa al OP.
2. Son preguntas referidas estrictamente a código.

*¿Debería un usuario común y silvestre, y/o moderador editar la pregunta agregando el código fuente que ha sido puesto en los comentarios (por parte del OP) para ponerlo en la pregunta?*

No.

### El fundamento del por qué "No."

La mayoría de preguntas que tienen código fuente nulo y/o enlaces con pastebins, son generalmente hechas por usuarios con poco tiempo en el sitio, inclusive están sin la `medalla de informado`. Por lo tanto hay una cosa para hacer: enseñarle a usar el sitio.

**Guiar al usuario es el camino**

*Si el OP se toma el trabajo de poner código.*

¡Enhorabuena! Hay diversas preguntas que tienen problemas de formato, ahí perfectamente encaja el asunto de editar y colaborar con darle formato a su código. Hay un esfuerzo de por medio, esfuerzo que merece ser apoyado.

*Si el OP no pone código, ¿podemos crear código por él para que encaje en su pregunta?*

No. Hay que guiarlo, pedirle que edite la pregunta y coloque lo mínimo necesario para reproducir su escenario.

*Si el OP no pone código y luego en los comentarios aparece código de la pregunta por parte del OP, ¿podemos agregar ese código a la pregunta?*

De poder, podemos, sin embargo, considero que no deberíamos porque esa tarea debería ser del OP, quizás desconoce la función de editar, por lo tanto se le explica que existe dicha opción y santo remedio, siguientes preguntas que le haga falta de código, podrá ponerlo luego de haber publicado la pregunta, habrá aprendido que existe dicha opción, también es probable que en siguientes preguntas incluya lo necesario antes de mandar la pregunta con baja calidad.

*Si el OP no pode código y en los comentarios no hay nada referente al código que debería estar en la pregunta, ¿se debería crear código de la nada para que encaje en la pregunta?*

No, ¿por qué? Porque la pregunta de por sí es de baja calidad y si se desea colaborar, se debe instruir al OP para que haga las ediciones correspondientes. Por más "notorio" que sea el ejemplo al que se refiere el OP, se debe instruir al OP para que coloque ese ejemplo "notorio". Si la gente se deja guiar desde el inicio, será muchísimo más fácil que elaboren preguntas de calidad, del mismo modo, podrán responder con calidad.

### Exigir == sugerir || Exigir != sugerir

Desconozco si esto tiene connotación cultural: pedir*, solicitar*, sugerir*, recomendar* ¿es lo mismo que exigir*? Para fines simples y evitar perder tiempo en discusiones sobre terminología que puede ser vista en la RAE: https://dle.rae.es/exigir, el uso de cualquier palabra con asterisco* viene a tener la misma finalidad: que exista una acción por parte de un usuario.

### Para finalizar

Hay quienes se dejan guiar y todo fresh.

Hay quienes les importa poco o nada porque "esa es tu opinión y no la comparto", y también fresh~ no pasa nada, nadie viene a pelear ¿o sí?

Hay quienes seguirán haciendo lo que le da la gana, inclusive algunos votando negativo a diestra y siniestra cuya consecuencia termina hasta en lágrimas e incomodidades en algunos usuarios.

Sigo pensando y sigo creyendo que el sitio mejora por efecto de la interacción adecuada de sus usuarios, que este tema se manifieste (otra vez) es para recordar que todos tienen teclado para expresar su opinión; habrán votos a favor, votos en contra, comentarios y todo ello genera impacto para tomar acción.

Es viernes, son las 6:06pm hora local, se completó la semana laboral y pues, espero que tengan un excelente fin de semana.

Fredy.

PD: Aprovechando su atención, les invito a "Las chocolatadas online" de este 2024, hay como 4 publicaciones, revisen, anímense a participar y voten (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meetups)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esta pregunta merece una respuesta mía ya que fui yo quien comentó a Yussef sobre pedir el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) al OP.

Y aunque Trauma ya dio una buena respuesta del porque no se debería poner un código a una pregunta sino que debe hacerlo el mismo OP, daré mi opinión.

Pueda que en SOes existan muchas reglas no escritas que se hacen para mejorar el sitio (algunas no me gustan pero las cumplo), una de ellas es el **Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable** que sirve para ver si el OP ha intentado algo, aunque sea buscar en Google o ChatGPT, lo que sea que nos demuestre que no solo viene, hace la pregunta y espera venir en dos horas para un código listo y funcional.

Que importa que solo fuera un `input` si en Google hay ejemplos de `input time` con mix y max, con algo así ya "podemos asumir" que por lo menos el OP no solo viene para que le hagamos todo, algo como poner enunciados de tareas y esperar la solución, para eso creo que aun existe el rincón del vago.

Cuando un usuario pone código en un comentario, siempre se le insta a **editar la pregunta** y agregarlo, lo hacemos a diario, todos. A no ser que el usuario esté realmente perdido y no entienda, se le puede ayudar con la edición, pero en este caso desde el inicio no se hicieron las cosas como debe ser.

Yo también quería responder a esa pregunta, pero mientras el OP no me diera a entender que hizo algo, no podía responder. Si yo invierto mi tiempo en analizar y probar algunos escenarios, lo mínimo que espero es que quien pregunta también lo haga.

---

Con el tema de las ediciones no me voy a meter pues no tuve nada que ver, y así como me dijo Yussef, cuando tenga la suficiente reputación para votar para cerrar algo lo haré, pero por el momento solo me limité a pedir que el usuario aportará su trabajo antes de darle un código.

Comment: Quiero aclararte una cosa: cuando yo te señale que no tenias la reputación suficiente para cerrar, en ningún caso fue para demeritar tu opinión. Era para señalarte que en ese momento te vas a encontrar con un menú de opciones parar cerrar una pregunta, el cual indica todos los posible motivo de cierre y que (según mi opinión) ninguno aplica a ese caso, y que por lo tanto si no existe motivo de cierre, es una pregunta puede ser respondida

Comment: 1- Yo no voté ni quise cerrar la pregunta, mi tema era la falta de esfuerzo del OP. 
2- Que la pregunta sea interesante (muchas lo son para mi) no significa que no pida SIEMPRE al OP su EMV. 
3- Se ha fijado que el OP no ha vuelto a decir nada? Eso me indica a mi, FALTA DE INTERES. Sorry @Yussef, usted me cae bien, pero creo que no erré en lo que hice. Disculpe lo que ocasioné con ello.

Comment: Yo soy de su época también. El rincón del vago (el 95%) se caracterizó por resúmenes o trabajos ya listos para descargar o solo copiar y pegar. No es lo mismo un foro o SOes, y si dice eso lo remito a ver el primer comentario (de Mau) que hicieron a su respuesta. Disculpe las molestias que causé y espero que esto quede acá.

Answer (score -3):

Las normas del sitio son claras al respecto, siempre se puede editar una pregunta (y una respuesta también) para mejorarla. Y se debe reversar esa modificación siempre y cuando la edición haya cambiado la intención del autor.

Lo que digan usuarios en META no es relevante, son solo opiniones personales. Supongo yo (y como SOes **no es una dictadura**) que si hay bastante conceso en algo, esto deberá verse reflejada en el centro de ayuda, y no es el caso.

Entiendo y comprendo que hay usuarios que piensan que no es correcto agregar código desde fuentes externas y/o comentarios, es "hacer el trabajo por el OP", bien por ellos, no lo hagan. Pero si quieren que esto sea una norma, son ellos los que deben abrir una publicación en META solicitando el cambio, no pretender que uno cumpla la reglas personales de algunos....al menos claro que esto si sea una dictadura

Comment: Esto: **Lo que digan usuarios en META no es relevante** me hace pensar que nunca te ha importado el sitio, la comunidad y sus normas. Que un usuario con casi 20K de reputación afirme eso, es cuando menos *desconcertante*.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Al contrario me importan mucho las normas, pero las que existen, no las que se inventan

Comment: Bueno, tu comentario y tu respuesta  **no son relavantes** según tus propias palabras.

Comment: Evidentemente, solo lo que está escrito en centro ayuda

Comment: Lo que dice el centro de ayuda, es como una guía con baches y zonas grises... aquí en meta tratamos de dialogar y establecer los parámetros de trabajo dentro de esas zonas grises... de cierto modo tenemos que adecuarnos a como la comunidad modera el sitio... de lo contrario esto seria un tira y jala todo el tiempo sin sentido, desgastante y sin un punto de unificacion de criterios...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover No, el centro de ayuda es ley. Aquí en META podemos debatir para cambiar las normas, si el cambio es aplicado debe reflejarse en el centro de ayuda, de lo contrario cualquier nuevo usuario debe leerse todo el centro de ayuda y las 2.000 publicaciones en META, es que no tiene sentido. Imagina fuera en SOen serian millones. Estamos de acuerdo que existen áreas grises, pero me parece que este no es el caso, la norma es bien clara que puedo editar para mejorar como sea, porque lo importante es que la publicación quede correcta no importa quien la realizó

Comment: @Yussef tratas el sitio como si se tratara de una nación o Estado. Hablas de dictadura y de leyes. Pues te pondré un ejemplo. Si un Estado posee una Constitución, esa es la Ley Fundamental por la que se rige, luego existen debates sobre leyes y reformas de leyes, que no están escritas en la Constitución. Piensa en el Centro de Ayuda como esa Constitución. Y las publicaciones de Meta como esos debates. Ahora, yo soy emigrante, he llegado a una nueva Nación, leo la Constitución de dicha nación, por encima, porque es muy larga...

Comment: ¿Es ridículo leer todas las leyes debatidas que no están en la Constitución? ¿Habría que añadir todas esas leyes y normativas a la Constitución para que sean parte de la Ley Fundamental? Pides que se añada todos y cada uno de los acuerdos y debates de Meta en el Centro de Ayuda? ¿No es eso más ridículo aún? Supongo que vas por la calle sin acatar las normas municipales o provinciales porque no están plasmadas en la Constitución del país en el que vives. Al final, es ridículo leer todo el conglomerado de leyes, normas y estatutos que se han discutido en tu país.

Comment: Por útlimo, y por eso mi comentario inicial. Sabes que el propósito de Meta es precisamente tener un lugar donde plasmar todo aquello que no está en el Centro de Ayuda. ¿Qué es Meta? Me quedo con la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4742/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-meta-y-stack-overflow-en-espa%c3%b1ol/4743#4743) de @fedorqui sobre el tema: Meta es el "Acerca de" del sitio, donde se puede encontrar preguntas y respuestas sobre la forma en que funciona el sitio y cómo moderarlo. Es precisamente el lugar donde la comunidad decide mediante el voto, estos asuntos.

Comment: Pero entiendo que te cueste aceptarlo, porque para ti, Meta no es relevante. Lamento que tengas esa actitud hacia Meta y lo que representa. No vas a encontrar un lugar en el Centro de Ayuda que exponga explícitmante la Norma que buscas, porque la moderación del sitio no está estipulada o escrita en piedra por la red de StackExchange, sino que cada sitio perteneciente a la red usa o establece sus propias normas. Y si a eso le quieres llamar Dictadura, entonces es la Dictadura de la Comunidad y no de uno o dos moderadores electos.

Comment: Cambiemos el punto de vista un poco, que tal que en vez de agregar el codigo en un comentario,el OP agrega una imagen en la pregunta.. es decir, cualquier Usuario le va a transcribir ese codigo a la pregunta? obviamente que no, la idea de modificar es solo para dar formato al texto

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso lo han hecho... si es corto el código o si es un mensaje de error...

Comment: Una cosa es la ley del estado, otra son las cosas que hace la gente. Pasar un semaforo en rojo es ilegal, sin embargo, la gente en mi país lo hace. Si el estado es corrupto, hay una brecha entre ambos grupos de leyes. Eso es lo que pasa aquí: el centro de ayuda son las leyes del estado, en meta están, mas o menos, las normas sociales. En conclusion: es mas ley lo que dice meta que lo que dice el centro de ayuda

Comment: @MauricioContreras No trato al sitio como si fuera una nación, eso te lo inventaste tu y me disculparás pero prefiero ni discutir analogías. Lo de que está escrito en piedra no lo entendí. Pero estamos de acuerdo que cada sitio puede crear sus normas, Meta es el sitio para debatir esos cambios, al llegar a acuerdo esos cambios deben quedar plasmados en el centro de ayuda. Una línea: "Solo el OP puede agregar código a su pregunta", no es tanto verdad? Otra línea: "No se deben responder preguntas donde el usuario no haya demostrado un esfuerzo por responder su propio problema", tampoco cuesta

Comment: De lo contrario, y si fuera como tu dices. Todos los reclamos que me hacen cuando respondo preguntas que algunos consideran inapropiadas no tendría sentido, porque en META existe una publicación que indica que si es valido. ¿No se puede colocar código de un comentario a la pregunta? También hay publicaciones que validan ese acto, pero hay otras que no ¿A cual le hago caso? Un usuario pregunta por un modelo de datos, le cerramos la pregunta, pero resulta que hay una publicación en META que dice que podemos aceptar preguntas que aceptarían en " Database Administrators"

Comment: Y por si fuera poco, en este caso particular ni siquiera es que no esté centro de ayuda, es que derechamente el centro de ayuda anima a realizar ediciones profundas y no cosméticas. Entonces quien manda, el centro de ayuda o meta????

Comment: Yo opino que lamentablemente meta. Meta es más acertado en cuanto lo que espera la comunidad que el centro de ayuda. Eso es un problema que pocos hemos notado o percibimos como tal. Por eso no uso ni acepto citas del centro de ayuda como argumento.

Comment: **Entonces quien manda, el centro de ayuda o meta????**, he allí tu problema, separas el Centro de Ayuda de Meta. Cuando son un todo. El Centro de Ayuda habla de ediciones *profundas*, y Meta te indica cuán *profunda*. Porque es un término *interpretable* y cada comunidad lo interpreta a su manera. En [es.so], se ha establecido, mediante Meta, que no puedes añadir código no existente en la pregunta. ¿Es eso lo suficientemente claro para ti? Esa es la *profundidad* de las ediciones acordadas aquí. Si quieres cambiarlo, escribe la propuesta en META: *Propongo permitir este tipo de edición*

Comment: @MauricioContreras no estoy del todo de acuerdo. El centro de ayuda puede llegar a contradecir a meta. Por ejemplo, el centro de ayuda dice "busca *en el sitio* si tu pregunta fue respondida" y meta dice "busca *en internet* si fue respondida. Y si, ya hice una propuesta en meta queriendo cambiar eso.

Comment: @DanteS. Nuevamente, y espero por útlima vez: El Centro de Ayuda está traducido a todos los idiomas que existen de [so], por lo cual, cualquier cambio que se haga debe ser global. Si tu propones que se incluya un link a Meta o una norma específica, se va a reflejar en todos los sitios. Es por ello que la forma de moderación no se deja tan explícita en el Centro de Ayuda. Aún más, hay muchas cosas del Centro de Ayuda que son genéricas, es decir, para toda la red SE. Es por ello que cualquier modificación al mismo has de hacerlo en Meta SE.

Comment: Si deseas que [es.so] adopte una norma específica sobre la moderación, se hace la propuesta en Meta Español, y si la misma es aceptada (mediante los votos positivos) se toma esa norma como tácita al sitio y no es necesario incluirla en el Centro de Ayuda, aunque tu consideres que se contradice una con otra, en este caso, priva lo que la comunidad ha decidido en Meta. ¿Cuesta tanto entender esta forma de moderación? ¿No es suficiente leer todo lo que hay escrito acerca de Meta, tanto en el sitio en inglés como aquí? Las propuestas aceptadas son acuerdos de moderación, y se aplican al sitio.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Yo lo entiendo, se que meta dice la casi verdad absoluta de la comunidad. Sin embargo, te hago una pregunta "por que esperan que un usuario sepa usar el sitio si el centro de ayuda, primera impresión del sitio, hay cosas que no son acordes a Meta?" Yo no digo que el centro de ayuda debe tener todo, pero si que esté completo. En fin, voy a proponer en meta general una fragmentación del centro de ayuda, para, al menos, so es. Por que se volvió una cosa casi inutil.

Comment: Primero, lo propondré acá, para ver si tiene apoyo

Comment: Parece que arreglaron el centro de ayuda desde la ultima vez que lo vi! Me alegro!

Comment: @MauricioContreras Creo que estás equivocado, el centro de ayuda no es global para todos lo sitios, de lo contario habría algo de caos en [on-topic] para los sitios de política, judaísmo, anime, etc-. Ni siquiera el ejemplo del unicornio es global para todos los sitios